# Getting SMPP error codes from server simulator

Tags: java, simulator, smpp, jsmpp

I'm using Server simulator from official jsmpp examples and I want to get smpp error codes(like ESME_ROK) from the server sim.
I use simpleSubmitExample and SimpleSubmitSimpleReceive (from official exmples) for sending messge and it works fine, but i need to get ESME_ROK from the server(in logs or as server output)
How to achieve that? thx.

link to jsmpp https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/jsmpp